# Decode utf8 error traceback in speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use google api with the speech_recognition library of python but debugging return me a decode error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]Google Text To Speech.py", line 22, in <module>
    r.recognize_google(audio)
  File "[...]\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 845, in recognize_google
    response_text = response.read().decode("utf-8")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

And when a try to recognize with microphone device the traceback its the same.

Its that because the google api requery a key as all others (like  IBM and Bing) or I'm just dumb?

The code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
voice = sr.AudioFile('maybe-next-time.wav')
with voice as source:
    audio = r.record(source, duration=4)
r.recognize_google(audio)
```

And thats the print of the "line 859" without the decode utf8 "print(response.read())":

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xff\xaaV*J-.\xcd)Q\xb2\x8a\x8e\xad\xe5\x02\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x03\x00\xf2\x0c\xcc\xd5\x0e\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: google ships a default API for testing purpose, so it shouldn't be an issue. But i dont think the error is related to that.
Can you share the entire traceback, so that we can see the line causing the error

Comment: I just did a clean install using `pip install SpeechRecognition` and used your code - I didn't get any errors, and received "maybe next time" with a `print`

Comment: @Vivek, there it is the full traceback.

Comment: @Tjofoed, I often have problems with
SSLCertVerificationError to install packages with pip, that must be something?

Comment: @Marcos can you try hitting this along - `r.recognize_google(audio,show_all=True)` [link](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instancerecognize_googleaudio_data-audiodata-key-unionstr-none--none-language-str--en-us--pfilter-union0-1-show_all-bool--false---unionstr-dictstr-any)

Comment: @Vivek, The traceback its the same ;-; I still thinking thats some SSL problem... Dont u?

Comment: @Marcos not sure if SSL issue would give such an output. Maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: @Vivek I have tried another decodes, tried encode to decode, tried microphone, other wav files, convert wav files to 16-bit and traceback still the same :v  I still have no idea :/